# On what criterion compiler chooses one of the overloaded method

Tags: java, overloading

What is the formal reason of prefering one to method to the other(by compiler)?
Why it chooses first one for bytes etc. I know that int can represent bytes, but float also. Why is it so formally?

```
public class MethodCurrier {

    public void setValue(int wrt){//naglowek
        System.out.println("Typ int "+ wrt);
    }
    public void setValue(float wrt){//naglowek
        System.out.println("Typ float "+ wrt);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MethodCurrier currier = new MethodCurrier();
        currier.setValue(4);//int
        currier.setValue(2.3f);//float
        currier.setValue('c');//char
        currier.setValue((byte)4);

    }
}
```

Comment: Interview question? Did you get the job?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Java Language Specification [defines](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5) this as follows:

> If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a method invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the descriptor for the run-time method dispatch. The Java programming language uses the rule that the most specific method is chosen.
>
> The informal intuition is that one method is more specific than another if any invocation handled by the first method could be passed on to the other one without a compile-time type error.

In your case, the `int` method is more specific than the `float` method, because an `int` can be implictly converted to a `float`, but not vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

Because the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2) says so.